# Express/TS/Apollo: Property does not exist on type

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, graphql, apollo

I'm currently building out an API gateway using Apollo. I'm currently building some auth into it, and I an auth microservice running behind my gateway and it's able to authenticate user credentials and return a JWT - no issue here.

However, now I've come to implementing the middleware on my `apollo-server-express` gateway, and I'm getting an error that I'm struggling to resolve when I try to pass the decoded JWT payload into the context.

For reference I've been following this guide: https://www.apollographql.com/blog/backend/auth/setting-up-authentication-and-authorization-apollo-federation/

```js
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express';
import { ApolloGateway, IntrospectAndCompose, RemoteGraphQLDataSource } from '@apollo/gateway';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import express from 'express';
import { expressjwt } from 'express-jwt';

dotenv.config();
const app = express();

app.use(
    expressjwt({
        secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET!,
        algorithms: ['HS256'],
        credentialsRequired: false
    })
);

// If we're in local development we're going to bypass the managed federation and use Introspect and Compose
const gateway =
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
        ? new ApolloGateway({
              supergraphSdl: new IntrospectAndCompose({
                  subgraphs: [{ name: 'OSC-Auth', url: process.env.AUTH_API_URL }]
              }),
              buildService({ name, url }) {
                  return new RemoteGraphQLDataSource({
                      url,
                      willSendRequest({ request, context }) {
                          request?.http?.headers.set(
                              'user',
                              context.user ? JSON.stringify(context.user) : ''
                          );
                      }
                  });
              }
          })
        : new ApolloGateway({
              buildService({ name, url }) {
                  return new RemoteGraphQLDataSource({
                      url,
                      willSendRequest({ request, context }) {
                          request?.http?.headers.set(
                              'user',
                              context.user ? JSON.stringify(context.user) : ''
                          );
                      }
                  });
              }
          });

const server = new ApolloServer({
    gateway,
    context: ({ req }) => {
        const user = req.user || null; // Error here on .user
        return { user };
    }
});

async function startServer(server: ApolloServer) {
    await server.start();
    server.applyMiddleware({ app });
    app.listen({ port: 4000 }, () =>
        console.log(` Gateway ready at http://localhost:4000${server.graphqlPath}`)
    );
}

void startServer(server);
```

What I believe is meant to happen, is `expressjwt` should decode my JWT payload and append it to the req object, which when initialising the `ApolloServer` I should be able to pull in and pass into the Apollo context for the gateway (then I should be able to pass that to my subgraphs via `willSendRequest`).

The error I'm getting:

`Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.ts(2339)`

I have also noted in the `express-jwt` docs, that the latest version defaults to `auth` and not `user`. Unfortunately, looking for `req.auth` generates the same error, just for `auth` instead of `user`.

If I log out the `req` object, then I can see the `auth` property, and it contains my JWT payload, but I still can't access it.

I have since extended the express `Request` interface, and added my auth object definitions. However, this only fixes the errors in VScode, and I still get the error on compile.

Worth noting that my background is heavily PHP based, and I'm currently transitioning into the JS/TS ecosystem, so any detailed explanations of any new concepts you think are relevant or I'm missing/miss-understanding would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If it is just a typescript error, you can add `// @ts-ignore` above the line, to get code to work, until you figure out why augmentation is not working.